# random effect formula in lmer

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model

I'm wondering how to go about fitting the following linear mixed model in R. Suppose I have three variables: response, subject and treatment. I observe 4 responses per subject, and a subject is either assigned to treatment or isn't (binary indicator). I want to fit the linear mixed model with covariance structure

$$
\text{Cov}(Y_{is}, Y_{jt}) = \sigma^2_0 \delta_{ij} \delta_{st} + \sigma^2_1 \delta_{ij} 1\{t(i)=1\} + \sigma^2_2 \delta_{ij} 1\{t(i)=0\}.
$$

Here, $i$ ranges over subjects, and $s$ ranges over different observations made on the subject. $\delta_{ij} = 1$ if $i=j$, and $t(i)$ is the value of the treatment assigned to subject $i$.

In words, I want to have a variance component for treated subjects and another for untreated subjects. How should this be coded up in R? say using lmer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm unsure about **lme4**, but this is straightforward with **nlme**.

The syntax is

```r
lme(response ~ 1, data = data,
    random = list(subject = pdDiag(form = ~ treatment - 1)))
```

where `data` is a data frame with columns `response` ($Y_{is}$), `subject` ($i$), and `treatment` ($t(i)$).

Comment: could you please explain what subject=pdDiag(~treatment -1 ) is doing? what is the design matrix being used here?

Comment: `pdDiag` is a constructor for a positive-definite diagonal matrix. We're specifying that we want to include the subject as a random effect, that the variance of the random effects varies by treatment group, and that the effects of different treatment groups are uncorrelated.

Comment: If we don't include the `-1` after `treatment`, it will assume that the random effects for the first treatment group have variance  $\sigma_1^2$, while the ones of the other groups have variance $\sigma_1^2 + \tau_j^2$ for $j=2,3,\ldots$

Comment: It should be possible in **lme4** via `lmer(response ~ 1 + (0 + treatment || subject), data)`.

Comment: Yes, good point. I don't think we need the `||` here, as there are only random slopes (no intercepts).

Comment: What I find a bit confusing in the **lme4** syntax is that the model summary contains an estimate of `Corr` for the treatment random effects. What does this correspond to?